# Running a .NET Core console app on another PC (as .exe)

Tags: c#, exe, asp.net-core-2.1

I made a server app in .NET Core 2.1. When I build it and run the .exe on the PC it was built on, it works just fine. The console stays open because Console.ReadLine() is called. However, the moment I put it (including all the associated files/dll) on a USB drive and try to run it on my laptop, the console pops up shortly and closes itself immediately. My laptop also has Visual Studio installed including .NET Core 2.1. In fact, I built the same application on my laptop and it worked there as well without any issues. But when I tried to run the .exe that I built on my laptop on my main computer, that did not work either.

I googled this issue and mostly it was said that it would be a framework issue, but I can't find the issue.. I hope someone can assist me. I've not built an .exe in Visual Studio before and this issue keeps me busy - it's exams time and there is much more to do. Any tips/help would be welcome.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfqP3.png

Comment: When you run it in a cmd window it shows something?


Win+R -> type cmd -> Enter -> drag exe file -> press enter

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did not try that.

"An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Server.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version: '2.1.13'
    path: 'runtimes/win-x64/lib/netcoreapp2.1/Microsoft.CSharp.dll' "

But the file is there, right next to the .exe and it is not empty either..

Comment: Possibly the "missing" assembly is there, but cannot be loaded due to a missing required assembly

Comment: You have to make a self-contained deployment if your target machines won't have .NET Core runtime preinstalled, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment

Comment: That did it! I set the self-contained deployment option before, but must have messed something else up when I did it. I published it again and it worked fine, thanks everyone!